# paper about black branes and implications to 4d black holes

Tags: string-theory, black-holes

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2127) makes a case for piezoelectric response (electric dipole moment under mechanical oscillations) of black branes. This paper does not make an implication of their results for 4D black holes (do their results apply or not apply to them?).

Can someone explain if this implies something for usual 4D black holes in De Sitter space? Do "standard" black holes have such a response as well?